# Where do I put the JQUERY UI theme folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code. It turns my text box into a date picker.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}template/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}template/js/jquery-ui-all.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#start_date").datepicker();
        $("#end_date").datepicker();
    });
    </script>
```

Where do I put the `ui-lightness` folder? It contains the images and js of the theme.  Right now, the images and CSS are blank on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place it anywhere you like, but you need to link the the CSS file to have it affect your page.

You need the default CSS

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/jquery-ui.css" %>" />
```

And the control specific files as well, for instance the dialog would need.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Content/ui.dialog.css" %>" />
```